# how to get the start and end dates of all weeks between two dates in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to get all week start and end dates(weeks) between two dates and then run a query returning the number of records inserted in each of those weeks.

```
declare @sDate datetime,
        @eDate datetime;

select  @sDate = '2013-02-25',
        @eDate = '2013-03-25';

--query to get all weeks between sDate and eDate

--query to return number of items inserted in each of the weeks returned



WEEK                  NoOfItems
-----------------------------------------
2013-02-25            5
2013-03-4             2
2013-03-11            7
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the list of dates:

```
;with cte as
(
  select @sDate StartDate, 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @sDate), 6) EndDate
  union all
  select dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate),
    dateadd(ww, 1, EndDate)
  from cte
  where dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate)<=  @eDate
)
select *
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9547).

Then you can join this to your table, to return the additional details.

Comment: is it possible to get the end of week date of that week in the EndDate column?

Comment: Note that this will fail in certain circumstances when the dates are a certain "distance" apart. Whereby you'll hit a maximum recursion level. In order to avoid this, append "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)" after your "select * from cte"

Comment: Is it possible to set monday as the first day?

Comment: @FrenkyB You'd want to look at setting [DATEFIRST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

Comment: @FrenkyB I think it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/66593958/2467036

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071427/2467036) answer

```
DECLARE @sDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
DECLARE @eDate DATE = GETDATE()
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @sDate), 0) AS StartDate, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @sDate), 6) AS EndDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, 1, StartDate), DATEADD(WEEK, 1, EndDate)
  FROM cte
  WHERE DATEADD(WEEK, 1, StartDate) <= @eDate
)

SELECT * FROM cte
```