# Results from query values in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am just curios about something I've never come across in sql server before.

This query:

```
SELECT N FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) T(N)
```

gives me result:

```
+---+
| N |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
```

What is the rule here? Obviously this is aligning all values into one column. Is sql server's grammar that defines this with `T(N)`?

On the other side, this query gives results by separate columns:

```
select 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I just don't understand why results from the first query aligned all into one column?

Comment: That looks familiar ^.^

Comment: Indeed :) I am studying your CTE magic from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42797191/867703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James Z is right on the money, but to expand on what it does in the answer you were referencing:

In the code that is pulled from, that section is used to start numbers table for a `stacked cte`. The numbers themselves don't matter, but I like them like that. They could all be 1, or 0, it would not change how it is used in this instance.

Basically we have 10 rows, and then we are going to cross join it to self `N` number of times to increase the row count until as many or more than we need. In the `cross join` I alias `n` with the resulting amount of rows `deka` is 10, `hecto` is 100, `kilo` is 1,000, et cetera.

Here is a similar query outside of the function that you were referencing:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select [Date]
from dates;
```

The `stacked cte` is very efficient for generating or simulating a numbers or dates table, though using an actual `numbers` or `calendar` table will perform better as the scale increases.

Check these out for related benchmarks:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

In hist articles, Aaron Bertrand creates a stacked `cte` using

```
;WITH e1(n) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b),
....
```

Answer (score 3):

The values clause is similar what you can use in the insert statement, and it's called [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx). Your example has only one column and several rows, but you can also have multiple columns separated by comma. The T(N) define you the alias name for the table (T) and name for the column (N).